# Package siunitx Error: Invalid numerical input 'E'. $RET$&

Tags: tables

I'm creating this table that has both numbers and words.

```
 \documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float,lipsum,subfig}
\usepackage{adjustbox,tabularx,ragged2e}
\usepackage{amsmath,geometry,booktabs}
\usepackage{mathtools,array,dcolumn,longtable}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hsize=#1\hsize}X}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt} % default: 6pt  % '2pt' is not exactly much
\usepackage[justification = centering]{caption}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}    
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\newrobustcmd{\B}{\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\singlespacing  
\begin{longtable}{S[table-format=2.0]
        *{3}{S[table-format=2.1]}
        S[table-format=2.1,detect-weight]
    }
    \caption{}
    \label{tab:descr_stat_es}\\
    \toprule
    {Geological fm.} &{L mean} &{L std} &{R mean}  &{R std}\\
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead
    \caption[]{}\\
    \toprule
    {Geological fm.} &{L mean} &{L std} &{R mean}  &{R std}\\
    \midrule
    \endhead
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
    \multicolumn{5}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{Continued on the next page}}
    \endfoot
    \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot
    $MAC$&  377.9&  41.7&   14.4&   1.8 \\
    $MAC$&  423.9&  36.5&   15.8&   1.9 \\
    $MAC$&  425.3&  33.3&   14.0&   2.6 \\
    $MAC$&  466.3&  56.8&   20.8&   5.6 \\
    $MAC$&  499.8&  86.4&   20.2&   7.0 \\
    $MAC$&  538.8&  45.3&   26.3&   2.4 \\
    $MAC$&  543.7&  47.4&   26.5&   2.8 \\
    $MAC$&  588.1&  122.7&  40.1&   7.2 \\
    $MAC$&  601.7&  143.7&  44.1&   5.6 \\
    $MAC$&  614.5&  54.4&   27.4&   2.9 \\
    $MAC$&  623.7&  80.7&   33.7&   4.7 \\
    $RET$&  636.7&  121.9&  35.7&   6.9 \\
    $RET$&  691.2&  51.4&   40.9&   5.0 \\
    $MAC$&  710.3&  59.6&   39.0&   4.3 \\
    $MAC$&  761.3&  60.3&   57.7&   2.3 \\
    $MAC$&  762.9&  41.6&   58.5&   1.5 \\
    $MAC$&  766.8&  36.2&   56.4&   2.0 \\
    $MAC$&  767.0&  49.7&   58.9&   1.8 \\
    $MAC$&  774.0&  39.1&   59.2&   2.3 \\
    $MAC$&  780.0&  64.2&   57.0&   2.5 \\
\end{longtable}
\onehalfspacing

\end{document}
```

I got this error:

```
Package siunitx Error: Invalid numerical input 'E'. $RET$&
```

How can I tell latex that the first column is not a numeric input?

Comment: Don't use  the `S` column type. You can use, for instance, `>{$}l<{$}` to avoid having to type  a pair of `$ $` for each entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the `S` column type for the first, i.e., left-hand-most column: That column contains no numbers -- with or without decimal markers -- so nothing useful is going to be achieved by using the `S` column type here. Instead, use the basic `l` column type -- and get rid of the `$` math-mode initiators and terminators.

Also, don't load packages -- such as `setspace`, `geometry`, and `lipsum` -- more than once.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float,lipsum,subfig}
\usepackage{adjustbox,tabularx,ragged2e}
\usepackage{amsmath,geometry,booktabs}
\usepackage{mathtools,array,dcolumn,longtable}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash%
       \hsize=#1\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt} % default: 6pt  % '2pt' is not exactly much
\usepackage[justification = centering]{caption}
%%%%\usepackage{setspace}  % don't load packages repeatedly
%%%%\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}    
%%%%\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\newrobustcmd{\B}{\bfseries}

\begin{document}

%\singlespacing   % <-- not needed for 'longtable'
\begin{longtable}{@{}
             l
        *{2}{S[table-format=3.1]}
             S[table-format=2.1]
             S[table-format=1.1]
    @{} }
    %% header and footer information
    \caption{}
    \label{tab:descr_stat_es}\\
    \toprule
    {Geological fm.} &{L mean} &{L std} &{R mean} &{R std}\\
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead

    \caption[]{}\\
    \toprule
    {Geological fm.} &{L mean} &{L std} &{R mean} &{R std}\\
    \midrule
    \endhead

    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
    \multicolumn{5}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{Continued on the next page}}
    \endfoot

    \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot

    %% body of longtable
    MAC&  377.9&  41.7&   14.4&   1.8 \\
    MAC&  423.9&  36.5&   15.8&   1.9 \\
    MAC&  425.3&  33.3&   14.0&   2.6 \\
    MAC&  466.3&  56.8&   20.8&   5.6 \\
    MAC&  499.8&  86.4&   20.2&   7.0 \\
    MAC&  538.8&  45.3&   26.3&   2.4 \\
    MAC&  543.7&  47.4&   26.5&   2.8 \\
    MAC&  588.1&  122.7&  40.1&   7.2 \\
    MAC&  601.7&  143.7&  44.1&   5.6 \\
    MAC&  614.5&  54.4&   27.4&   2.9 \\
    MAC&  623.7&  80.7&   33.7&   4.7 \\
    RET&  636.7&  121.9&  35.7&   6.9 \\
    RET&  691.2&  51.4&   40.9&   5.0 \\
    MAC&  710.3&  59.6&   39.0&   4.3 \\
    MAC&  761.3&  60.3&   57.7&   2.3 \\
    MAC&  762.9&  41.6&   58.5&   1.5 \\
    MAC&  766.8&  36.2&   56.4&   2.0 \\
    MAC&  767.0&  49.7&   58.9&   1.8 \\
    MAC&  774.0&  39.1&   59.2&   2.3 \\
    MAC&  780.0&  64.2&   57.0&   2.5 \\
\end{longtable}
\onehalfspacing

\end{document}
```

Comment: Fantastic explanation, thank you @Mico!!!! :D